# SCP to copy files from vmware machine remotely

Tags: linux, scp

I have 2 machines `A1(Windows11)` and `A2(Linux Mint)` on 2 different networks `N1(Korea)` and `N2(Japan)` respectively.
Inside `A1` I install a Linux guest `A11` and now I would want to copy a file from `A11` to `A2`.
I've found no tutorial online that helps me from scratch. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
you@a11 $ scp files* user@a2:/path/
```

or

```
you@a11 $ rsync -avP files* user@a2:/path/
```